# Orchard - Ajax displaying just partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, orchardcms

I am working on an Orchard project and I am trying to get my ajax code working in there.

Here is the view:

```
    @model Ignite.Events.ViewModels.EventListPartViewModel
@{
    Script.Require("jQuery");
    Script.Include("EventList.js").AtLocation(Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceLocation.Foot);
    Script.Include("fullcalendar.js").AtLocation(Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceLocation.Foot);
    Script.Include("EventCalendar.js").AtLocation(Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceLocation.Foot);
    Script.Include("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js").AtLocation(Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceLocation.Foot);
    Style.Include("fullcalendar.css").AtLocation(Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceLocation.Foot);
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEventListItems", "Events", new { area="Ignite.Events", month = 4, year = 2013 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "event-list", HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}, new { id = "ajaxForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <input type="submit" value="Get Next" />
}
<table id="event-list" class="event-list">
    @Html.Partial("_EventList", Model.Events)
</table>

<div id="calendar" class="clear"></div>
```

Here is a controller that is returning the partial view:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult GetEventListItems(int? month, int? year)
        {
            if (month == null || year == null)
            {
                month = DateTime.Now.Month;
                year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            }

            var result = _eventListDataService.GetEventListItems((int) month, (int) year);

            return PartialView("_EventList", result);
        }
```

I am wondering why I always get just the partial view and not the complete view with the partial view rendered in it.

Thank you,

Jakub

Comment: Isn't that what you want? This is confusing.

Comment: No, I would like to get the partial view displayed in my view. Now I am getting just the partial view.

Comment: Still confused, sorry. Can you give a step-by-step explanation of what you are trying to do, what you attempted and how it failed?

Answer (score 0):

Only the partial view is being rendered because that is what `GetEventListItems()` is returning: `PartialViewResult`.

What happens when you change the return to `ViewResult`?

You will also need to decorate the method (or the Controller) with `ThemedAttribute(true)`.